# How can I switch from Bluetooth Discoverability mode to device discovery mode in android

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, bluetooth

I have a question regarding Bluetooth br/edr for android devices.I have a different type of requirement, In which a local device should discover nearby devices as well as local device should be discoverable same time to other device.
How long(minimum duration) I should do Inquiry and Inquiry scan so that I can receive all the devices in the range.
I am new for android and Blueooth br/edr.Any help will be appreciated.
Apology,if question is duplicate.